# Not able to retrieve messages from topic using EMS.NET API

Tags: tibco-ems, ems, tibco-topic

I am trying to write a simple application to send messages to a topic from use input and show messages published on topic.
There are two command line executables - one for publisher and another for subscriber.
When I publish messages on a topic, I can see the messages getting submitted to the topic.

The following command shows that there are messages on the topic (see F1.gif):-

```
show stat EMS.Test.Topic
```

[image]

The following command shows that the messages are getting consumed by the subscribers (see F2.gif)

```
show stat consumers topic=EMS.Test.Topic
```

[image]

However, I am not able to retrieve messages the EMS .NET API. It gets stuck on `Message msg = subscriber.Receive();`. I made sure the connection details and authentication details are correct because they are used when publishing the messages.

```
public string ReceiveMessagesFromTopic(string topicName)
        {
            TopicConnection connection = null;
            string messageFromPublisher = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                var factory = new TIBCO.EMS.TopicConnectionFactory(serverUrl);
                connection = factory.CreateTopicConnection(userName, password);
                TopicSession session = connection.CreateTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                Topic topic = session.CreateTopic(topicName);
                TopicSubscriber subscriber = session.CreateSubscriber(topic);
                connection.Start();
                while (true)
                {
                   Message msg = subscriber.Receive();
                    if (msg == null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (msg is TextMessage)
                    {
                        TextMessage tm = (TextMessage) msg;
                        messageFromPublisher = tm.Text;
                    }

                }
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (EMSException e)
            {
                if (connection!=null)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }


                throw;
            }

            return messageFromPublisher;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a silly mistake in my .NET code. the following while loop never returns so there is no return. I need to break the while loop when I get a message. Duh!!!!

```
 while (true)
 {
         Message msg = subscriber.Receive();

         if (msg == null)
         {
             break;
         }
         if (msg is TextMessage)
         {
             TextMessage tm = (TextMessage) msg;
             messageFromPublisher = tm.Text;
             break;
         }

 }
```

Comment: hi, even for me, the control is stopping at subscriber.receive.  it does not go to line if (msg == null) itself. if there are no messages in the topic, then the control does not move to next line itself.  so am wondering if above is the correct solution...